# PHP ZIP creating subfolders as files

Tags: php, zip, directory

I have some PHP code that I am using to try and zip a folder. The folder has two subfolders in it and several individual files.

Here is the code: -

```
<?php

    $src = $_POST['srcin'];
    $dst = $_POST['dstin'];

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($dst, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    if (false !== ($dir = opendir($src)))
         {
             while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
             {
                 if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
                 {
    $ans = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                           $zip->addFile($src.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);
                 }
             }
         }
         else
         {
             die('Can\'t read dir');
         }
    $zip->close();

    echo json_encode('Folder Compressed');

?>
```

The input values are: -

srcin = "TestFolder"
dstin = "TestFolder.zip".

What is happening is that I am getting a zip file. However, the subfolders are being created as files.

I got the above code from searching this forum on how to ZIP a folder, yet I cannot see anything mentioned regarding subfolders not being zipped properly.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Martin

Comment: From the looks of it, it doesn't check if anything under the `$src` is a folder/directory and acts accordingly.  Maybe create a possibly recursive function and check if `$file` is a directory, if so, pass it to the function to read through it.  Recursive would be my suggestion so you can pass the `$src` to that function as well.  I can't really create an answer with any code as you don't state what library you are using so I wouldn't be able to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a directory with `addEmptyDir` before you add a file to it.

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ziparchive.addemptydir.php) is an example(see top comment) how to archive a directory recursively

Comment: I have tried some of the examples on that link. It appears the example marked with the description "Here's a stack-based way to zip a directory. No recursion, no function, no class: " seems to work. Although I am getting an error from the PHP. God knows why.

Comment: I am calling the PHP from AJAX Using the code error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert("ZIP " + xhr.status); alert(thrownError); I Get two popups. The first has 200 in it, the second says "JSON Parse, unexpected end of data" I have been doing PHP for about 20 hours now.

Comment: Fixed the errow now also. I used echo json_encode instead of just echo.